# Передать функцию через props React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Есть класс `App`, в методе `render` я вставляю компонент `Proposal`:

```
{this.state.proposals.map(proposal => <Proposal name={proposal.name} key={proposal.id} id={proposal.id} handleEvent={this.handleEvent} votes={this.getProposalVoteCount(proposal.name)}/>)}
```

Вопрос заключается в votes `{() => this.getProposalVoteCount(proposal.name)}`

`getProposalVoteCount()` обьявлена в этом же классе, возвращает число, написана правильно.

Тем не менее число сразу не возвращается в `props`, а в консоль выходит ошибка:

```
index.js:1446 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Так вы определитесь, у вас там лямбда в параметре или просто вызов функции

Comment: Я хочу сделать вызов функции , который в props вернет число. как правильно это будет реализовать?

Comment: как используете `votes`?

Comment: а зачем вы функцию в `state` храните?

Comment: @ThisMan, спасибо за поправку , сейчас отредактирую вопрос, без state, но проблема остается та же

Comment: тот код который сейчас должен прокидывать число в пропс, а вот если используете стрелочную функцию, то в пропсе будет просто функция

Comment: @ThisMan votes  я просто вывожу в компоненте Proposal. Да, именно это мне и надо, мне нужно чтобы функция возвращала число

Comment: Перечитай ошибку и подумай, в чём разница между "передавать" и "выводить".

Answer (score 0):

Попрубуйте обернуть ваш вывод в методе `render` во фрагмент:

```
render() {
    return (
        <>
            {this.state.proposals.map(proposal => (
                <Proposal
                    name={proposal.name}
                    key={proposal.id}
                    id={proposal.id}
                    handleEvent={this.handleEvent}
                    votes={this.getProposalVoteCount(proposal.name)}
                />
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```

Подробнее о фрагментах можно почитать [тут](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).